# Python find root for non-zero level

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, solver

Say I have the following code

```
def myfunc(x):
    return monsterMathExpressionOf(x)
```

and I would like to find numerically the solution of `myfunc(x) == y` for diverse values of `y`. If `y == 0` then there are a lot of root finding procedures available, e.g. from scipy. However, if I'd like to find the solution for e.g. `y==1` it seems I have to define a new function

```
def myfunc1(x):
    return myfunc(x) - 1
```

and then find it's root using available procedures. This way does not work for me as I will need to find a lot of solution by running a loop, and I don't want to redefine the function in each step of the loop. Is there  a neater solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@Evert's answer shows how you can do this by using either a [closure](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Closure_%28computer_programming%29) or by using `functools.partial`, which are both fine solutions.

Another alternative is provided by many numerical solvers.  Consider, for example, [`scipy.optimize.fsolve`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.fsolve.html).  That function provides the `args` argument, which allows you to pass additional fixed arguments to the function to be solved.

For example, suppose `myfunc` is x**3 + x

```
def myfunc(x):
    return x**3 + x
```

Define one additional function that includes the parameter `y` as an argument:

```
def myfunc2(x, y):
    return myfunc(x) - y
```

To solve, say, `myfunc(x) = 3`, you can do this:

```
from scipy.optimize import fsolve

x0 = 1.0  # Initial guess

sol = fsolve(myfunc2, x0, args=(3,))
```

Instead of defining `myfunc2`, you could use an anonymous function as the first argument of `fsolve`:

```
sol = fsolve(lambda x, y: myfunc(x) - y, x0, args=(3,))
```

But then you could accomplish the same thing using

```
sol = fsolve(lambda x: myfunc(x) - 3, x0)
```

Answer (score 2):

You don't have to redefine a function for every value of `y`: just define a single function of `y` that returns a function of `x`, and use that function inside your loop:

```
def wrapper(y):
    def myfunc(x):
        return monsterMathExpressionOf(x) - y
    return myfunc

for y in y_values:
    f = wrapper(y)
    find_root(f, starting_point, ...)
```

You can also use [`functools.partial`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functools.html#functools.partial), which may be more to your liking:

```
def f(x, y):
    return monsterMathExpressionOf(x) - y

for y in y_values:
    g = partial(f, y=y)
    find_root(g, starting_point, ...)
```

Read the documentation to see how `partial` is roughly implemented behind the scenes; you'll see it may not be too different compared to the first `wrapper` implementation.

Comment: Thanks, but does not this essentially defines a new function `f` at each iteration of `for`? That is, each function for which I'd like to find a root I'll need to define using this wrapper?

Comment: Yes, because you're root finding function probably wants a function that only depends on `x`.

Comment: Is there  a way to define a function `f(x,y)` and then define `g` such that `g(x) = f(x,1)`?

Comment: That's pretty much what I have written above; it's just that your way of writing it down is mathematically better. But in code, you can't (some things/languages excepted) write `g(x) = f(x, 1)`; it just doesn't make sense. Instead, you write `g = f(1)` and the variable `x` is implicit.

Comment: Thanks, this indeed looks nicer